# Robocopy Invalid Parameter /BYTES

Tags: windows-7, robocopy

I would like to use robocopy with the `/BYTES` parameter. When I use it I receive an invalid parameter error:

```
ERROR : Invalid Parameter #6 : "/BYTES"
```

I am using Windows 7. When I do a `robocopy /?` I get this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows     ::     Version XP010
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Version XP010 does not have the `/BYTES` parameter, but Windows 7 was supposed to ship with version XP027, which does. When I check the version of robocopy.exe it says `5.1.10.1057`, which I believe is XP027.

What gives? Can anyone help me out with this?

References:

- http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy#Versions

Edit:
I found a hotfix for robocopy and updated to version `6.1.7601.22012`, but the error still occurs.

Comment: It would help if you posted the full command you are running.

Comment: I suppose it would have. It was just a simple copy, nothing fancy. I knew the command itself was fine - it was solely the `/BYTES` parameter causing strife.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely have an old version in a directory listed in your path before `C:\Windows\System32\` which is where robocopy is normally located. To find out where your copy is running from run `where robocopy`. On a regular system the result would be:

```
C:\>where robocopy
C:\Windows\System32\Robocopy.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\robocopy.exe

C:\>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this was exactly the problem. I feel kinda silly for not realising it myself. I didn't install the Windows Resource Kit on this machine, it must be part of my work's SOE.